# bootstrap Tooltip Stays Open (IE, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Solved. Code will reflect changes (and have comments)**

I'm going to try and describe the issue succinctly first and then provide detail.

I'm using bootstrap's tooltip to display some text when hovering over a table data element under a single column in a table. To get to this table, you navigate to it through clicking an item under a dropdown list. After having chosen the dropdown item, if you're mouse is coincidentally hovering over a table element that has a tooltip as the table/page is being rendered, the tooltip remains open/stuck on the page (in **IE** and **Firefox** only).

Below is the JavaScript that renders the table and generates tooltips. I'm using a KendoGrid to generate and keep track of the information being pulled from the database. jQuery, bootstrap, knockout, and Kendo are the bases for the front end of this web page.

Is there something I can reformat to solve this issue? Or a known workaround anywhere? All input is appreciated. Thanks!

**JavaScript**

```
var createGrid = function () {
    $('#AvailableAttachments').html('').kendoGrid({
        columns: self.AvailableColumns(),
        dataSource: {
            data: [],
            sort: self.Type() == 'Labor' ? { field: 'Description', dir: 'asc' } : { field: 'ReferenceNumber', dir: 'asc' }
        },
        selectable: true,
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: true,
        resizable: true,
        change: self.AttachmentGridChange,
        dataBound: self.availableGridDataBound
    });
};

var updateGrid = function () {
    /*Destroy all previous table's tooltips*/
    $.each($('#AvailableAttachments').data('kendoGrid').table.find('tr'), function (i, row) {
        $(row).find('td.hoverDescription').tooltip('destroy');
    });

    createGrid();
    var selectedCategory = {
        /*Grab some parameters*/
    };

    app.ajaxLoadingPanel = '#AvailableAttachments .k-grid-content';
    $.getJSON(app.baseUrl + self.Type.peek() + 'Attachment/Get', selectedCategory, function (data) {
        var oldSort = $('#AvailableAttachments').data('kendoGrid').dataSource._sort;
        var newDS = new kendo.data.DataSource();
        newDS.data(data);
        if (typeof oldSort != 'undefined' && oldSort.length > 0) {
            newDS.sort(oldSort[0]);
        }
        $('#AvailableAttachments').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(newDS);
        filterFavorites();
        $('#btnEditPart').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#btnDeletePart').prop('disabled', true);

        $.each($('#AvailableAttachments').data('kendoGrid').table.find('tr'), function (i, row) {
            generateToolTip(row);
        });
    });
}

function generateToolTip(row) {

    var description = /*Do some parsing to get the information to display*/
    ...
    ...
    $(row).find('td.hoverDescription').attr('data-original-title', description);
    $(row).find('td.hoverDescription').tooltip({ container: '#AttDescriptionToolTip', placement: 'left', html: true, opacity: 0.7 });
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing tooltip hiding needs "onmouseleave" event in the bootstrap core. Since the element has already disappeared, the tooltip stays open. I mostly write a custom JS funtion to remove all visible tooltip elements from  body and call it in almost every button click events.

Comment: Do you mind going into more detail? How has the element disappeared when it hasn't appeared yet?

...Or it's rooted in a different issue where my table is rendering twice, and thus like you said, that element is gone and another one (though with the same content) has taken its place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This was an issue with the cache retaining the previous table's content before rerendering the information. I had to manually call destroy on the tooltip so that such scenarios wouldn't occur before updating my table.

```
$('row').find('td.hoverDescription').tooltip('destroy');
```

I'll update my code above to reflect this.